# How to disable Linux file read cache in favour of ZFS ARC

Tags: linux, zfs

Most of the answers to related questions here seem to assume the person asking thinks linux is "eating their ram" or come up with workarounds such as dropping caches every minute from cron.

This is not what I want to achieve, instead I want the linux file cache disabled for good and rely solely on the ZFS ARC for caching files in memory.

Answer (score -2):

`nocache` - minimize filesystem caching effects

https://github.com/Feh/nocache

Might not work with all applications.

Comment: *Might not work with all applications.*  Quite an understatement.  Don't use that unless you want to make any multithread process deadlock-prone.  If you use that and your process does something as simple as try to `fork()` then `exec()` another process, if it tries to close file descriptors between the `fork()` and the `exec()` (like lots of things do....), the way that library uses mutexes is going make the child process deadlock-prone.  And that's what I get from looking at the code for about three minutes...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Patches are welcome :-) I do understand your resentment but no one has written a better utility yet :-) In fact it's the only one for Linux at the moment.

Comment: Resentment?  No, I just have higher standards.  That code entirely breaks the async-signal-safety of every function it intercepts. Did you even realize that?

Comment: So, no patches and downvotes for a single utility which allows to disable caching? What a nice website we have here.

Comment: You posted a link-only answer to unreliable code, then labelled my pointing out some problems with that code as "resentment".  And I'm guessing you didn't realize that code breaks the async-signal-safety of every function it intercepts.  It isn't even large-file-aware for 32-bit applications, which likely opens the door to data corruption if it's used there - and you've had an open issue on ***that*** for almost five years.  Deadlocks, broken standards, data corruption?  And you complain about ***this*** site?  Don't push crap code.

Comment: 1) I have **not** written this code, also I'm **not** a C coder, so I have no clue whether it's properly written or not 2) This utility works for lots of people 3) it's used by **Debian** among all distros 4) There are **no alternative utilities** for Linux 5) You continue to strongly criticize me and the guy who wrote it without even submitting a bug report 6) You've offered nothing. God, what have I done wrong to earn such flak. Thank you for **downvotes**, it's kinda despicable what what do I know. Maybe you've had a bad day or a week but I haven't deserved anything that you've thrown at me